# Select a column by criteria *and* the column name in each row of an R dataframe?

Tags: r

If I have a dataframe of election results by district and candidate, is there an easy way to find the winner in each district in R? That is, for each row, select both the maximum value *and* the column name for that maximum value?

```
District   CandidateA   CandidateB   CandidateC
1          702          467          35
2          523          642          12
...
```

So I'd want to select not only 702 in row 1 and 642 in row 2, but also "CandidateA" from row 1 and "CandidateB" in row 2.

I'm asking this as a learning question, as I know I can do this with any general-purpose scripting language like Perl or Ruby. Perhaps R isn't the tool for this, but it seems like it could be. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
d <- read.table(textConnection(
"District   CandidateA   CandidateB   CandidateC
1          702          467          35
2          523          642          12"),
header=TRUE)                

d2 <- d[,-1]  ## drop district number
data.frame(winner=names(d2)[apply(d2,1,which.max)],
           votes=apply(d2,1,max))
```

result:

```
      winner votes
1 CandidateA   702
2 CandidateB   642
```

Do you need to worry about ties? See the help for `which` and `which.max`, they treat ties differently ...

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't too messy, you can try running a `for` loop and printing out the results using `cat`. So if your `data.frame` object is `x`:

```
for(i in 1:length(x$District)) {
  row <- x[i,]
  max_row <- max(row[2:length(row)])
  winner_row <- names(x)[which(row==max_row)]
  cat(winner_row, max_row, "\n")
}
```

Comment: That makes sense using the same logic I'm familiar with, thanks. Just tried it and works perfectly (It is definitely going to take me some time to learn R syntax.)

Comment: Just noticed that in the 4th line, the `which` function is redundant, so you can reduce that to: `winner_row <- names(x)[row==max_row]`

Comment: or `winner_row <- names(x)[which.max(row)]`

Comment: `which.max` might cause a problem if there's ever a case where the District number is the maximum value in the list.